# Python : How do I look for '100%' as a string in a .txt file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a .txt file (eg. test.txt). Using python, I want to search the string "100%" in this .txt file. Please help.

```
       file = open('test.txt', 'r')
       for line in file.readlines():
           if '100%' in line:
               print "Successfully downloaded."
```

A portion of test.txt looks like:

```
6800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 98% 11.1M 0s
  6850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99% 10.4M 0s
  6900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .         100% 12.6M=2.3s
```

And I want to look for '100%' in this file.

Comment: file = open('test.txt', 'r')
    for line in file.readlines():
        if '100\%' in line:
           print "Successfull."

Comment: what you have is fine, except you need to indent the print and drop the backslash.

Comment: Not working even after indenting the print and dropping the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you call "searching", here's a version:

```
lines = open('file.txt').readlines()
i = 1
for line in lines:
    if "100%" in line:
        print ("Line %s:" % i), line,
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '100%' in line:
            print 'found'
```

the `with` means that the file, which is opened as `f`, will be closed when you are done.  the `for line in f` gives you each line in turn (and may be more memory friendly than reading everything first with readlines()).

but what you have looks fine to me if you drop the "\" and indent the print.  what error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error but it is not able to search "100%" in the file.

Comment: yeah even after removing "\", "100%" is not getting searched in the file.

Comment: just a guess, but is that file being added to as you search?  because you'll need to re-run the program as more lines are added to the file.  and have you tried putting something like `print '**', line[0:10], '**'` inside the loop to make sure it's seeing lines?

Comment: hey, this actually helped to see what the problem is. It is not reading the whole file. When I say print `'**', line[:], '**'` in th e for loop,   it is not reading till the end of file. So it is not able to see 100% . But whys is this happeing.

Comment: It prints as `**
**   4600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 66% 11.3M 1s
**
**   4650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 67% 1.19M 1s
**
**   4700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 68% 11.1M 1s
**
**   4750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 69% 10.9M 1s
**
**   4800K .......... .......... .......... .......... ...... **
`

Comment: As seen it reads only till 69%, but there is more in the file.

Comment: hmm.  i don't have any more ideas at the moment, sorry.  maybe someone else will see this...